# Importing FMU in Dymola using importFMU function

Tags: modelica, dymola

I'm trying to Import FMU in Dymola using the following syntax:

```
importFMU(fileName="xyz", includeAllVariables=false, integrate=true, promptReplacement=true, packageName="abc");
```

It gives me this error:

> Error: declaration window line 3 column 10, syntax error at "("
>   missing { identifier   "[" }

What am I missing?

Comment: What Dymola version are you using? In last version, 2016FD01, your command is working jsut fine, maybe you entered wrong filename or packageName, or have errors inside the "abc" package.